# Return books that contain specific genres

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to retrieve the object that contains specific genres based on show variable value

```
const books=    
    "genres" : [
        "history"
    ], 
    "title" : "Yemen", 
    "published" : NumberInt(1990), 
    "author" : ObjectId("5ef5fb84b368d90d48e785a1"),  
},{"genres" : [
        "Web", 
        "Programming", 
        "Development"
    ], 
    "title" : "JavaScript for Profissional", 
    "published" : NumberInt(2016), 
    "author" : ObjectId("5f046ddc4a55f425d86311d0"),},
{"genres" : ["Programming"], 
    "title" : "CSS for Profissional", 
    "published" : NumberInt(2019), 
    "author" : ObjectId("5f046ddc4a55f425d86311d0"), 
}
```

This is the books object.
I want to get the books that contain specific genres

like that

```
const show="programming"
const booksToShow =
    show === "All"
      ? books
      : books.filter((book) => book.genres.map(g=>{
       if(g.toLocaleLowerCase()===showAll.toLocaleLowerCase()) 
          return book
      }
     )
```

**everything executed perfectly but it doesn't return any value into booksToShow while it supposed to return this object**

```
{"genres" : [
        "Web", 
        "Programming", 
        "Development"
    ], 
    "title" : "JavaScript for Profissional", 
    "published" : NumberInt(2016), 
    "author" : ObjectId("5f046ddc4a55f425d86311d0"),}
```

**so are there anyway to repair this problem**

Comment: The syntax used in your book sample is unusable, can you edit it ?

Comment: It should be show.toLocaleLowerCase instead of showAll.toLocaleLowerCase ?

Comment: it is retrived from the mongodb i did it here to show you the books object while it is retrieved from the database

Comment: The `map` should be outside and after the `filter` or else it returns **undefined**. Actually, you just need filter tbh

Comment: the error not in the syntax the syntax is right when you set show into "All" it works not this problem

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx yes this is what i want but how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of your ternary condition can work using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to know if your books contains at least the given genre once :

```
books.filter(book => book.genres.some(g => g.toLocaleLowerCase() === show.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

I have some performance concerns about this solution though. You may want to apply `toLocaleLowerCase()` to all books either once the data is received or directly within your database to avoid doing this operation every time your component re-renders.

By doing so you will be able to replace `some` by [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), drastically improving your perfs:

```
books.filter(book => book.genres.includes(show))
```

Comment: Good to know. Keep my second advice in mind if you plan on processing a lot of books

Answer (score 1):

Solution with a double filter:

```js
const books=  [{ 
    "genres" : [
        "history"
    ], 
    "title" : "Yemen", 
    "published" : 1990, 
    "author" : "5ef5fb84b368d90d48e785a1"
},{"genres" : [
        "Web", 
        "Programming", 
        "Development"
    ], 
    "title" : "JavaScript for Profissional", 
    "published" : 2016, 
    "author" : "5f046ddc4a55f425d86311d0"
    },
{"genres" : ["Programming"], 
    "title" : "CSS for Profissional", 
    "published" : 2019, 
    "author" : "5f046ddc4a55f425d86311d0",
}];

const show="programming".toUpperCase();
const booksToShow = show === "All" ? books : books.filter((b) =>
  b.genres.filter((g) => 
    g.toUpperCase() === show
  ).length > 0);

console.log(booksToShow);
```

Comment: thank you sir the problem was solved by @Treycos answer and your answer is right too